# Recursive function returns the smallest interval that enclose all other intervals

Tags: python, recursion

I have a recursion function that has to returns the smallest interval that encloses all intervals in ​`l`​. Example: [(2,4),(3,5),(3,6)] → (2,6)

```
def minint(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    return (min(l[0][0],minint(l[1:])[0]),max(l[0][1],minint(l[1:])[1]))


print(minint([(2,4),(3,5),(3,8)]))
```

I can't understand how those [0] and [1] at the end of the `min` and `max` functions work. To me has more sense in this way:

```
def minint(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    return (min(l[0][0],minint(l[1:][0])),max(l[0][1],minint(l[1:][1])))
```

Why this is wrong and that is right?

Comment: Why use recursion for this case? Instead of a list comprehension

Comment: ^ What @Richie said. `return min(x[0] for x in l), max(x[1] for x in l)`. Yours will fail if `l` is longer than the recursion limit, and it's enormously wasteful anyway, something like O(n^2) plus call overhead instead of O(n) with no call overhead.

Comment: It is an exercise to understand recursive function

Comment: The worst exercises are those that teach you to approach a problem the wrong way.

Comment: Correction: based on some quick testing, it's O(2^n), which is worse than I thought.

Comment: At least you will learn what is recursion not good at..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it down

```
return ( # returns two integers: min and max
    min( # select the min of lower limit
        l[0][0], # either the from current tuple
        minint(l[1:])[0] # or the one returned from a recursion
    ),
    max( # select the max of the upper limit, notice `[1]`
        l[0][1],
        minint(l[1:])[1]
    )
)
```

So each call is kept open as it sends another call of the same function but with a smaller list  (`l[1:]` slices the list dropping the first element and it is passed to the new call).

Once the passed list is only one element then that last call returns the only element in the list (no need to evaluate min/max anymore). Then that returned element is used in the penultimate fubction call.

That penultimate call was already on this mega one-liner ready to evaluate `minint(l[1:])[0]` in the min part and `...[1]` in the max, e.g. the last call returned `(3, 6)` so the penultimate call evaluates `minint(l[1:])[0] = 3` and `minint(l[1:])[1] = 6`... (notice it made two different calls to a recursion, so it is probably O(n^4), a hell of a lot less efficient)

Once that penultimate evaluates those max and min to return the current extrema, the antepenultimate can start evaluating what it got, and so on up the stack of open calls. Until only the first call remains open and it gets the values it called for.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're basically undoing the slice. `l[1:][0]` is the same as `l[1]`.

That means `minint(l[1])` returns `l[1][0]`, which is a tuple, and on the next recursion, it returns `l[1][0][0]`, which is an int, and an error is raised.